# Meteor: How do I only allow the user to access on page?

Tags: meteor

I am using iron router, and I have a special type of account (certain value in Meteor.user().profile) and I am wondering if there is a way using iron router, that instead of having to put a restriction in every single route (except for home. login, etc) that I can simply only **allow** them one page?

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this page... http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-iron-router-filters-before-and-after-hooks

Basically, you can setup a global onBeforeAction hook that will run before each route, then redirect the user if needed to a default route. You can also use before for specific routes, here's the example from the page...

```
////////////////
// BeforeHooks
////////////////
// I use an object that contains all before hooks
var IR_BeforeHooks = {
    isLoggedIn: function(pause) {
        if (!(Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.user())) {
          Notify.setError(__('Please login.'));
          this.render('login');
          pause();
        }
    },
    somethingForAnyRoute: function() { ... },
    ...
    // add more before hooks here
}

// (Global) Before hooks for any route
Router.onBeforeAction(IR_BeforeHooks.somethingForAnyRoute);
...

// Before hooks for specific routes
// Must be equal to the route names of the Iron Router route map
Router.before(IR_BeforeHooks.isLoggedIn, {only: ['userAreaA', 'userAreaB']});
```

Also, triggering your route protection from something in Meteor.user().profile can be a bad idea, since the user can access and change anything in profile from the client console. This should be directly in the Meteor.user() object for security, then it is looked at server side. I'm not an expert in this area, so more research might be required if security is a concern.